# time complexity of metatable in Lua when accessing

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

```
local cls = {base = "base"}
local ins = {}
cls.__index = cls
setmetatable(ins, cls)
```

What is the time complexity of accesssing `ins.base`?

Comment: I believe the third line should be cls.__index = cls

Comment: right. My mistake @peterm

Comment: I think time complexity is same as for `cls.base`. You just add several hash lookup. Time complexity for hash lookup in best O(1) in worst is O(n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expect `O(1)` time complexity from the official Lua implementation.

The code for `__index` is roughly equivalent to this Lua code, taken from the manual:

```
 function gettable_event (table, key)
   local h
   if type(table) == "table" then
     local v = rawget(table, key)
     if v ~= nil then return v end
     h = metatable(table).__index
     if h == nil then return nil end
   else
     h = metatable(table).__index
     if h == nil then
       error(···)
     end
   end
   if type(h) == "function" then
     return (h(table, key))     -- call the handler
   else return h[key]           -- or repeat operation on it
   end
 end
```

The `__index` lookup itself has no loops, and since Lua tables are backed by hash tables, table lookups are usually a constant-time operation.